# How to filter based on referencing values? django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My model

```
class MyColumn(models.Modle):
   name = Charfield.....
   max = Integerfield....
   min   = Intigerfield....


Class MyCell(models.Model):
   Value = Integerfield.....
   Column = ForeignKey(NyColumn)
```

My goal is to get values that greater or equal the max or less than or equal the min. But, how to reference the max or min value from inside `MyCell.objects.filter`

```
MyCell.objects.filter(value__gte=value__MyColumn__max)
```

Comment: One of the things expected from a [mre] is that your example should not reproduce some _completely different_ problem than the one you face. You have _many_ typos in your example...

Comment: There is someone answered me well that is my goale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare your `MyCell.Value` and `MyColumn.max` with [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F).

```
from django.db.models import F

MyCell.objects.filter(Value__gte = F('Column__max'))
```

Comment: And `, Value__lte = F('Column__min'))` for the min

Comment: Depends on you. You know better which value belongs to which column. @ali al-karaawi